# Python fly check in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I installed [jorgenschaefer/elpy: Emacs Python Development Environment](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) on emacs.

but find the grammar checking is annoying.

[image]

I noticed that vscode also employed the [python/black: The uncompromising Python code formatter](https://github.com/python/black)

> The Python extension supports source code formatting using either autopep8 (the default), black, or yapf.

[Editing Python Code in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing)

but it display very clean

How could solve the problem in emacs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close `flymake` to mute the prompts.